How to join tables A and B, where each row in A contains an array of logical conditions to match in B
Consider these two tables
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `test.items` AS (
        SELECT 1 AS ID, 1 AS Foo, 100 AS Bar,
UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS ID, 1 AS Foo, 155 AS Bar,
UNION ALL SELECT 3 AS ID, 1 AS Foo, 219 AS Bar,
UNION ALL SELECT 4 AS ID, 2 AS Foo, 155 AS Bar,
UNION ALL SELECT 5 AS ID, 2 AS Foo, 200 AS Bar,
UNION ALL SELECT 6 AS ID, 2 AS Foo, 300 AS Bar
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `test.conditions` AS (
  SELECT 1 AS Foo, ["50..150", "2**"] AS Conditions,
  UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS Foo, ["3*0", "200..300", "155"] AS Conditions
)



I'm trying to design a query akin to a left-join of items onto conditions (retaining every condition and only matching items).

A given condition can match to multiple items
Column Foo must match in both tables
Column Bar in items can match any of the conditions in the Conditions array

To add to the complexity, Conditions uses a non-standard syntax whereby

M..N means "match anything from M to N (inclusive)
M*N means "match anything 3-character string starting with M and ending with N"
M** means "match anything 3-character string starting with M"
Otherwise, look for an exact match

I'm comfortable converting this logical syntax to regular expressions, but I'm struggling to architect the query design. I'm guessing I should use a LOGICAL_OR with a UDF.. Something like
WITH step1 AS (
  SELECT
    Foo,
    Bar,
    Conditions
  FROM `test.conditions`
  LEFT JOIN `test.items` USING(Foo)
)

SELECT * FROM step1 WHERE (LOGICAL_OR(MyFunc(Bar, Conditions)))


You can translate conditions
M..N -> value between cast(M as int) and cast(N as int)
M**  -> value like 'M__'
or-> value like 'M%'
Simple - replace '*' by '%' or by '_'.
See example.
BigQuery:
with cond as(
select foo,c
  ,case when c like '%..%' then 
          cast(left(c,strpos(c,'..')-1) as int)
        when c not like '%*%' then cast(c as int)
   end i1
  ,case when c like '%..%' then 
          cast(substr(c,strpos(c,'..')+2,100) as int)
        when c not like '%*%' then cast(c as int)
   end i2
  ,case when c like '%*%' then replace(c,'*','_')
   end p1
from(
  select foo,c from test_conditions,unnest(conditions) as c
 -- select foo,unnest(conditions)c from test_conditions
   )x
)
select *
  ,case when i.bar between c.i1 and c.i2 then 1
        when cast(bar as string) like p1 then 1
        -- when cast(bar as varchar) like p1 then 1
   else 0
   end fl
from test_items i
left join cond c on i.foo=c.foo

PostgreSql:
with cond as(
select foo,c
  ,case when c like '%..%' then -- range - take left  side
          cast(left(c,strpos(c,'..')-1) as int)
        when c not like '%*%' then   -- not interval, no wildcards -> single value
          cast(c as int)
   end i1
  ,case when c like '%..%' then 
          cast(substr(c,strpos(c,'..')+2,100) as int)
        when c not like '%*%' then cast(c as int)
   end i2
  ,case when c like '%*%' then replace(c,'*','_')  -- wildcards
   end p1
from(
select foo,unnest(conditions)c from test_conditions
)x
)
select *
  ,case when i.bar between c.i1 and c.i2 then 1
        when cast(bar as varchar) like p1 then 1
   else 0
   end fl
from test_items i
left join cond c on i.foo=c.foo

Test data
with test_items AS (
        SELECT 1 AS ID, 1 AS Foo, 100 AS Bar,
UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS ID, 1 AS Foo, 155 AS Bar,
UNION ALL SELECT 3 AS ID, 1 AS Foo, 219 AS Bar,
UNION ALL SELECT 4 AS ID, 2 AS Foo, 155 AS Bar,
UNION ALL SELECT 5 AS ID, 2 AS Foo, 200 AS Bar,
UNION ALL SELECT 6 AS ID, 2 AS Foo, 300 AS Bar
)
,test_conditions AS (
  SELECT 1 AS Foo, ["50..150", "2**"] AS Conditions,
  UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS Foo, ["3*0", "200..300", "155"] AS Conditions
)

Demo fiddle

You did notice that the question is tagged BigQuery, not PostgreSQL?

Yes, I see. Just now can not test query in BigQuery. Besides unnest, the rest is easily translated into the desired language

Query for BigQuery added to answer. You can see difference between BigQuery and PostgreSql)
